# NFS dir permissions changed not visible

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, nfs

I have an `nfs` storage mounted at `/mnt/data`.

This is mounted across several VMs in the same mountpoint.

I changed the permissions of the dir from `775` to `770`. The change is visible only in one VM. I did the same for a subdirectory e.g. `/mnt/data/foo`.

However if I change the permissions of a file within this dir, the permissions are common across all VMs.

Why this discrepancy?